# Maven: Include POM with used dependencies in assembly

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

We deliver our package with many external dependencies to customers. Now customers can use you libraries to develop stuff on top. For those who are also using Maven we would like to include a *pom.xml* file in the assembly which contains all dependencies, so they can simply use it in their Maven build:

It should contain all dependencies used by us as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to achieve that in Maven?

Answer (score 1):

The pom.xml for your jar/war is by default placed inside your jar/war in the location `META-INF\maven\<groupId>\<artifacdId>`

Comment: True... but because we use a parent project for all sub projects which contains the versions of all libs, no versions are included in the POMs within the jar file.  I guess I will have to work something out manually.

Comment: Your customer need to just add/use your jars as their dependencies and the third-party jars their information is all inherited. Also, we usually keep parent and child pom versions in sync to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

The first one which is the most common and preferred way is relying on Maven's transitive dependency resolution.

Have a POM (assume called `foo-api:1.0`) in your project that declares the dependency (e.g. `A:1.0:jar`, `B:1.0:jar`).

Developer's own project (`bar:2.0`) should then simply depends on `foo-api:1.0`.  Maven will simply include `A:1.0:jar` and `B:1.0:jar` as dependency of `bar:2.0`, through the transitive dependency resolution.

Another way is similar to the above approach, but use `foo-api:1.0` as parent POM of `bar:2.0`.

Either way should work but which one is suitable depends on your design.